# Заменить 5 replace на 1 regexp | JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, регулярные-выражения

Очень мозолит глаза вот такая конструкция:

```
let url = NameController
                        .replace(`${root_path}/${_path_url}`, "")
                        .replace('.js', "")
                        .replace('index', "")
                        .replace(/\[/g, ":")
                        .replace(/\]/g, "")
```

в NameController следующая строка `D:/JS/vkma/api/controllers/test.js`

условия такие:
Нужно удалить все по слову controllers включая его... в итоге получаем `/test.js`

Далее если есть слово index НО оно в чистом виде... indexA удалятся не должно. Так же index заменять только в именах файлов. получается только если справа от слова есть " . "

Потом если у /test.js есть [ и ] то надо их заменить.. вот пример: `/[test].js` нужно получить `/:test.js`

Ну и последнее это удалить расширение файла `.js` чтоб получить `/:test` если были скобки... либо `/test` если скобок небыло.

Как реализовать подобное регулярное выражение?

Comment: Зачем? Оставьте так. Так хоть вполне понятно, что происходит

Comment: Только что-то ниже у вас совсем не то, что происходит описано))

Comment: Беспокоюсь о производительности этих replace один за одним

Comment: То есть у вас есть результаты профилирования и вы точно знаете, что вот эти строчки ваше бутылочное горлышко, а не что-то еще?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Заменяются ведь на разные вещи (на пустую строку или двоеточие), уже не получится одной регуляркой и без дополнительных операций. Если очень хочется убрать с глаз что-то многострочное, можно завернуть его в функцию.

Можно не удалять всё ненужное, а выбрать только нужное, через `match()`:

```js
console.log( get_name("D:/JS/vkma/api/controllers/test.js") );
console.log( get_name("D:/JS/vkma/api/controllers/[test].js") );

console.log( get_name("D:/JS/vkma/api/controllers/testindex.js") );
console.log( get_name("D:/JS/vkma/api/controllers/indexA.js") );
console.log( get_name("D:/JS/vkma/api/controllers/[testindex].js") );

console.log( get_name("D:/JS/vkma/api/controllers/index.js") );


function get_name(nameController) {
  let match = nameController.match(/\/\[?([^./]+?)(?:index)?\.js/);
  
  return match && match[1].replace(/\]/g, ":");
}
```

Справки:

- `?` — совпадене 0 или 1 раз, `\[?` — необязательная открывающая скобка.
- `([^./]+?)` — группа захвата (match вернет массив, в котором под [1]-м индексом будет всё, что совпало в скобках). `[^./]` — внутри квадратных скобок перечисляются символы, один из которых должен совпасть. Если список начинается с `^` (отрицания), читается «Все что угодно, кроме `.` или `/`», и `+` — один или много раз подряд.
- `(?:index)` скобки начинаются с `?:` — «не группа захвата».
- `match && match[1]` — Особенность логического "И": Если совпадения не будет и match вернет `null`, в логическом контексте это `false`. Вернется `null` и вторая часть выражения даже не будет вычисляться, не будет ошибки. Можно было заменить на if-else.

---

P.s.

> Беспокоюсь о производительности этих replace один за одним

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(test);
}

function test() {
  let start = performance.now();
  let x = "11111";
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    x.replace(/1/g, "2").replace(/2/g, "1");
  }
  
  console.log(performance.now() - start);
}
```

Справляется с миллионами, наверно можно не беспокоиться за +/-4 штуки) Длина строки тоже имеет значение, но она у вас короткая.

Comment: Чтобы index хоть как-то работал, наверное, стоит на предыдущий квантификатор поставить нежадный режим)

Comment: @vp_arth Упс, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

С index не вполне понятно, что именно нужно удалять.

```
const NameController = 'D:/JS/vkma/api/controllers/[test]index.js';
const base = require('path').basename(NameController, '.js');
// const base = NameController.split('/controllers/')[1].replace(/\.js$/, '');

let result = '/' + base
    .replace(/\[(.*)\]/, '$1:')
    .replace(/\bindex\b/g, '');

console.log(result); // /test:
```